# Paraphrases in the modern dialect of the language of the original

Tags: discussion

[User 'ChristopherE'](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/24593/8572) has my eternal, infinite thanks for (supernally) generously and helpfully introducing the [Early Modern Texts site](http://www.earlymoderntexts.com/)  developed by Philosopher Jonathan Bennett. So I thought to compose this post to share other  paraphrases or glosses, written in the modern (21st century) dialect of the language in which the original philosophy work was written.

Please beware that I ask *not* about translations of philosophy from one language to another language. All recommendations here must be written in the language of the original work, but in the modern dialect (eg: Old French -> Modern French, Middle/Early Modern English -> 2000s English).

Comment: This seems like it would be better suited for meta.philosophy.se than philosophy.se as there's no philosophical question here...

Comment: I've come across the Modern Early Texts site - it's definitely useful.